# error when installing matplotlib.h with vcpkg using Git Bash

Tags: python, c++, bash, matplotlib

```
git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg.git
cd vcpkg
./bootstrap-vcpkg.sh
./vcpkg integrate install
vcpkg install matplotlib-cpp
```

I tried running this code I got from https://github.com/lava/matplotlib-cpp to install matplotlib.h. I'm running the code from within Git Bash and whenever I run 'vcpkg install matplotlib-cpp' Bash responds with "bash: vcpkg: command not found"

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do not use the git or github tags just because you cloned a Git repository from GitHub. (See the tag descriptions that pop up if you hover your mouse cursor over the tags.) In any case, "command not found" indicates that the command you ran is not present in your `$PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the commands ran properly. Make sure that you use `"/"` instead of `"\"` in git bash. But the problem is most likely that you need to either add vcpkg to PATH or do `./vcpkg install matplotlib-cpp` instead of `vcpkg install matplotlib-cpp` while in the vcpkg folder. This is because Windows is weird and doesn't let you run local executables in terminal without `./`.

Comment: I tried all of the code on the site you sent, I got the same error as before for all three methods on that site

Comment: Check if the commands ran properly. I tried it out, and I had to make sure that I used "/" instead of "\" in git bash. But the problem is most likely that you need to either add vcpkg to PATH or do `./vcpkg install matplotlib-cpp` instead of `vcpkg install matplotlib-cpp` (in the vcpkg folder). Please confirm this so I can adjust the answer.

Comment: ```./vcpkg install matplotlib-cpp``` worked. Thanks.

Comment: But now Visual Studio says "Cannot open include file 'matplotlib.h': No such file or directory" when I run ```#include matplotlib.h```.

Comment: What do you get when trying `./vcpkg integrate install` again? Maybe it failed the first time (for example because you needed to run git bash as admin). Other than that, I have no clue, maybe try to google around the error a bit. I didn't find an answer for this specific case.